# Increasing size of ArrayList in ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am trying to increase the size of an `ArrayList` inside an `ArrayList` whenever a new value is added but I'm not sure on the correct way to do so. This is what I have right now:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outerList;

public int addValue(int value) {
    int a = 0;

    ArrayList<Integer> innerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if (noValue(value) == true) { // noValue checks if the value exists at a position in outerList and returns true if it's empty
            innerList.add(value); // innerList has now size 1
            outerList.add(innerList); 

    }

    else {
            a += 1;
            innerList.add(value);
            outerList.add(innerList);
    }

    return a; 

}
```

But based on my tests, the size of `innerList` remains 1.

Comment: You are just adding 1 item to it, so one would expect the size to be 1.

Comment: You're always using a new `ArrayList` for inner list. Your `else` block should add to the existing list instead of using a newly created one.

Comment: looks like you could use a  `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` or possibly a `Map<Integer, Integer>` (and only store how often you added the value) and use the `Map#compute` methods to simplify the code. E.g. `addValue(int value)` = `map.computeIfAbsent(value, i -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value)` with the map of lists.

Comment: BTW:  `if (noValue(value)) ` is sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But based on my tests, the size of `innerList` remains 1.

This is because in your `addValue()` method you create a new `innerList` and add it to the list. Thus your outer `ArrayList` will consist of a lot of `ArrayList`'s with only one object in them.

To change this you should use the [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) method to get the inner `ArrayList` and *then* add the item to it. Something like:

```
outerList.get(index).add(value);
```

Where `index` is the index of the inner list you want to add the value to

Answer (score 3):

You never *get* anything from `outerList`, all instances of `innerList` will always be newly created and then get one new entry added. Then that `innerList` is added to `outerList` and never touched again.